# Solr Admin Panel Returning 500 Server Error.

Tags: search, solr, lucene, jetty

I am configuring solr 5.5 and after starting the solr (bin/solr start), on accessing the admin panel, i see 500 error with description

HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /solr/. Reason:

```
Server Error
```

Caused by:

org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error processing the request. CoreContainer is either not initialized or shutting down.
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:191)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I took the zip from my friend's machine for which its working, and tried on my local, but same problem. Looks like some configuration problem with my machine.

Note : When i run the server on Clound mode (bin/solr start -e cloud -noprompt), i am able to access the admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

There are several different possibilities for why you get this error.

I recommend checking whether *clusterstate.json* is empty or not, which you can find in the Zookeeper-ensemble. It should only contain "{}".

Further on would I check whether you have any shards in the SOLR_HOME-folder, and thereon delete them. SOLR_HOME is normally found at ./server/solr/.

Hope that works!

Comment: Please explain more. I am not understand your instructions

Comment: Can you please confirm if the core.properties file in your core(s) is named uniquely:
#Written by CorePropertiesLocator
#Mon Jan 21 05:52:24 UTC 2019
name=myCore

Answer (score 0):

If you are giving your own folder for solr server. Make sure you have `solr.xml` copied there. This could be one of the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Please try increasing the memory on the configuration file

`/etc/default/solr.in.sh`

```
SOLR_JAVA_MEM="-Xms2g -Xmx2g"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten the same Exception, though the status code was 404 instead of 500.

One of the config files (/var/solr/data/security.json) contained some wrong key values. While removing this wrong key values from the file, solr started working normally again.